# Node / React start up issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I get the following error in my log when I issue `npm start`. Does anyone have any idea how to approach this? I am new to node and react. It appears that the issue could be due to my package.json file.

```
11 silly lifecycle myreact@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myreact@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: myreact@1.0.0 start: `npm run clean && npm run webpack && concurrently "npm run webpack:w"  "npm run web" "npm run rest"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid myreact@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\am\Documents\myreact
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.11.3
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myreact@1.0.0 start: `npm run clean && npm run webpack && concurrently "npm run webpack:w"  "npm run web" "npm run rest"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myreact@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What does your `./start.js` file look like? Or did you mean to write `npm start`?

Comment: yes when I run `npm start` to fire up my project I get this error. I do not have `./start.js` in my folder

Comment: Ah, I see. You question says `node start`, that's why I asked. Have you tried `npm install` before you run `npm start`?

Comment: yes. I have tried `npm install`. You are right I will edit to reflect `npm start'

Comment: My advice would be as a starter for 10 run each command you are attempting to execute in `npm start` manually, you seem to invoke a few and also run some via `concurrently` so best to start narrowing down which command(s) are causing the problem.